# Voice App with custom proxy ability

Tags: voice-command, proxy

I used to run [Siri Proxy](https://github.com/plamoni/SiriProxy) on my Mac mini, and it allowed me to build custom commands that Siri would respond to while I was on the same network.

> "Turn on the living room lights"
>   "Run the sprinklers"
>   "Dim the lights for a movie"

Now that I've moved to Android, I'd like to be able to achieve this same goal. Can anyone direct me to a solution whereby I can use some Voice App in combination with a local proxy to achieve this desired result?

Comment: Please note that app recommendation questions (*Is there an app for X?*) are off topic here. For details, please consult our [FAQ].

Comment: @Izzy: This looks like "here is a problem I am trying to solve" question to me.

Comment: @user267 On a second read, I guess it might be re-phrased such -- you might be right with that, Al. Even not that much to change (replacing "app/proxy combination" by "solution" might do), so I might have been a bit too fast with my conclusion. Chase: In case your question gets closed due to my comment, just ping me, so I can make up for it.

Comment: @Izzy I've edited the question to appear less `shopping`esque

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Thanks. As I wrote in my last comment: In case it gets closed, simply ping me. You'll almost always find me in chat here. Again, my apologies!